# Move/copy documents from sub site level 2 site library to sub site level 1 site document library using Rest API in SharePoint online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to move documents from child level sub site document library to parent site. I tried using rest api MoveTo/CopyTo methods. But these methods are working only when the target and source libraries are present in the same site.

My requirement is I need to move documents from sub site level2 (`https://SiteURL/Subsite1/Subsite2/LibraryName/filename.docx`) source library to sub site level1 (`https://SiteURL/Subsite1/LibraryName/filename.docx`) target library.

Please suggest me how we can achieve this using REST API or any client side in Office 365 SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file by REST API, and then upload to parent site by REST API like:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/rootfolder/files/add
```

Here is one similar thread for your reference:
[How to copy files between sites using JavaScript REST in Office365 / SharePoint 2013](http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html)